# Can't send CORS query: responds with "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a plain form that includes only one input of `type=file` that I need to parse.

And I have a `php` handler that is located on a different server. There I have these headers:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8;");
```

And here is my ajax query:

```
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/ajax.php', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");

        let post = 'ajaxquery=psScript&config=' + JSON.stringify({
            path_to_include: 'include.php'
        });

        xhr.send(post);

        xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
        })

        xhr.addEventListener('error', () => {
            reject();
        });
    }).then((response) => {
        console.dir(response);
    });
```

As stated in the title, it responds with `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`. Though if I change this:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
```

To this:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Data would be send. But this way, I suppose, I can't send file to the server.

It seems like a strange behavior to me. How do I solve that and why is this happening?

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) out for information on CORS. Basically you need to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from your PHP server. It is enforced at the browser level, so there is no way currently to circumvent the restrictions.

Comment: `there is no way currently` ... there is no way, and never will be, being able to circumvent CORS would be a very bad thing. `restrictions` - CORS isn't a restriction, it's actually the opposite of a restriction compared with pre-CORS

Comment: The issue in the question is probably that the pre-flight `OPTIONS` request isn't being handled at all, or correctly if it is being handled

Comment: @JamesHay I don't get it. It's said there that simple request may consist of `POST` query & content-type of `multipart/form-data`, same as in my example. It doesn't have to be preflighted and as I understand there should be only `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in my handler.

Comment: @Oscar That does not apply to the majority of XHR requests, as they need to be "pre-flighted" (you can read that section in the link). If your AJAX request is sending any additional headers, which it possibly is, or is not a standard allowed content type or HTTP method, it will first send an `OPTIONS` request, which must reply with the allow origin header.

Comment: @JaromandaX Same as the above. Why should I preflight it if it's a simple request? :\ I did send an options request though, no changes. So frustrating :\

Comment: @Oscar Check in your network request, it may have a header in the request like this `X-Requested-With: XmlHttpRequest` which will trigger the preflight.

Comment: `I did send an options request` - you mean, your browser automatically sent an OPTIONS request, which your server responded to correctly and within the CORS specifications .... and besides all that, that POST wouldn't be preflighted, so, sorry for the misdirection

Comment: @JaromandaX No, I manually sent an xhr. Here are the screenshot of response headers for an `OPTIONS` request: [link](http://i.imgur.com/oCUEsi0.png)
And response headers for a `POST` request: [link](http://i.imgur.com/6rTvjV9.png)
...

Comment: no need to send OPTIONS manually - the browser wouldn't see that as part of the "CORS" process anyway

Comment: @JamesHay Nothing like that, unfortunately

Comment: Do you notice that your response headers have no CORS headers in it ... that ties in with the error you're getting doesn't it - so the problem seems to be on the server

Comment: @Oscar Can you post the full HTTP request into the question?

Comment: @JamesHay That is the full request (besides I've added an `OPTIONS` that seems to be unnecessary). Or do you mean request headers?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, I did notice that (that seems even more ironically given the fact that if I change the content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, everything works perfectly). Can't get much out of it though.

Comment: @Oscar I mean the RAW request, you can get it out of dev tools in your browser. Something like this `GET /someurl HTTP/1.1
Host: my.localhost
Connection: keep-alive
....`

Comment: @JamesHay Yeah, sure. [link](http://i.imgur.com/y4pvAci.png)

Comment: @Oscar well the CORS is being triggered because the port number you are coming from is different to the port you are requesting. There doesn't appear to be any specific headers or information that violate the same origin policy, so it's likely an implementation by the browser for XmlHttpRequests, which as mentioned earlier, can not be circumvented. Maybe someone else can fill in the details here.

Comment: update: changed the query type to `GET`. It works now :\ Though I need it to be `POST`.

Answer (score 3):

In your php server you are setting the header to be `header("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8;");` so if you try to set the content type to be `multipart/form-data` it won't allow.

You need to set this header value in the server

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8;");
```

Comment: Same performance. Isn't it supposed to be the content type of a response data?

Comment: Yes it is, but it is send as an header but if your server doesn't allow that that of an header then you will get an error

Answer (score 0):

Added this:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

To my `.htaccess` file. That seemed to solve the issue.