# Get data with post using axios in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

How can I get data from an api that uses post to get data? Here is my code but the api does not return anything when I log the data.

Comment: which content-type the server support ?

Comment: multipart/form-data

Comment: set headers `multipart/form-data` in this request, `axios` default `Content-Type` is `application/json`.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Actually the content type is `text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Do you get an error that Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing???? If yes then please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094689/cant-send-cors-query-responds-with-no-access-control-allow-origin-header/41094754#41094754

Comment: No, I dont get that error

Comment: Here are the headers supported by the server:                               Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Connection →Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Content-Length →1859
Content-Type →text/html; charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the data you are trying to pass as the requests body is meant to be url encoded form data so, try this

```
axios.post('https://example.com/api?function=getSomething')
.then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `Content-Type` which the server support. `Qs` is `querystring` library.

```
axios.post('https://example.com/api', Qs.stringify({
    'function': 'getEvents'
}), {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

Code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5c3xycmm/), but it also get an error by `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, you may proxy yourself or change the server origin access allow.